# Can a Mobile Operator use Netflow same as used by a WireLine Operator

Tags: netflow

Can a Mobile Operator use Netflow same as used by a WireLine Operator to gain insights in to subscriber behavior. The reason I am asking this question is because the network typologies are very different.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented solutions for both types and you are correct in your point about different requirements. The number of netflow collection points is dramatically increased when deploying for a mobile provider as the have a lot of Point of Presence (PoP) for the last mile. The network complexity of many routes requires that the netflow product be smart about de-duplication of netflow for  accurate visibility.  Different network topologies also require different mitigation architectures. I would recommend a netflow solution that:
1. Handles de-duplication for complex networks easily and accurately - identify Core /Edge and so on.
2. Does not charge by users or objects protected so greater value in a large PoP deployment. Billing by overall flowrate is the easiest to budget, maximize value.
3. Play nice with others- To get the most from netflow, it needs to be shared and propagated to existing ops systems 
4. Scale and sustainability- The growth of mobile has increased flowrate, so having a system that can scale to unlimited flowrate, and handle all the storage and load balancing automatically if key.

I highly recommend the power of netflow to improve QoS and reduce costs for a mobile operator. Here is some additional detail from and blog post https://www.flowtraq.com/network-flow-analysis-for-maximum-security/

Bottom line- A netflow product with Topology awareness.

-Gurdev

Comment: Thanks Gurudev, we already have a netflow solution which makes use of Radius /DHCP to map the device centric netflow feed to a CSP subscriber. This is mainly used by our wireline operators. Now moving to mobile space I am not sure what AAA is used and what info we could use to map this to Flow records to a mobile subscriber. Do you have any insights to this?

Comment: The Radius / DHCP feature is unique to Lancope, but I think I understand the question better as it seems like a a flow tagging issue.  If the flow is generated at the endpoint that the phones connect to, then it would seem that the subscriber ID is actually available at that endpoint.  By that logic it would seem you could tag the flows with a custom IPFIX field, that includes the subscriber ID. Depending on the hardware/software that is running there, you might need to consider customizing your exporting logic.

Comment: Well asking a service provide to change the router exporting logic is a uphill task, what is a subscriber ID in mobile space(IMEI/IMSI?)? any info from IMS we could leverage to get the Flow to Subscriber mapping? I am not sure what mapping mechanism is usually deployed in the mobile world.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I've reached out to our Telco customers, who use wholesale services or shared routers, for any details on how they handle IMEI or sub ID in those cases. Our domestic telco customers were not so familiar with this approach, so I've asked a few in South America how they utilize netflow / FlowTraq to get that additional info. I will update as soon as I have intel